# Restrict TIME data type in mysql to hold only till 24:00:00 hrs

Tags: mysql

Actually i am using MySql 5.6.4 version.But the problem is that MySQL retrieves and displays `TIME` values in 'hh:mm:ss' format (or 'hhh:mm:ss' format for large hours values).

`TIME` values may range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. The hours part may be so large because the `TIME` type can be used not only to represent a time of day (which must be less than 24 hours), but also elapsed time or a time interval between two events (which may be much greater than 24 hours, or even negative).

I want to restrict `TIME` data type in mysql 5.6.4 version to hold only till 24:00:00 hrs, so if will insert the time which is greater than 24:00:00 then it will show error message.

I have googled a lot for this but i didn'yt find anything although i am bit confused... I just want to know How can i do it?

```
Insert into exp1.mock_table (reviewTime, created_dt) VALUES ('37:00:00', NOW());

Insert into exp1.mock_table (reviewTime, created_dt) VALUES ('22:01:53', NOW());

alter table exp1.mock_table modify reviewTime time(0) , add check (extract(hour from reviewTime) between 0 and 24);
```

Comment: You can set the insert trigger for these validation

Comment: for example


DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER foo
BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.birthdate > CURRENT_DATE()
  THEN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Warning: birthdate can not be greater than current date!';
  END IF;

END$$
    DELIMITER ;

Comment: you can make your own conditions inside that trigger

Comment: You can build the logic into the INSERT itself.

Comment: Where are the invalid values coming from in the first place?

Comment: @Dhaval Purohit yeah ok using TRIGGER it's right but it's throwing some error like SQL Error [1419] [HY000]: You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable

Comment: @Dhaval Purohit i have tried this....create trigger check_capacity_on_insert
before insert on exp1.mock_table
for each row 
begin
if(hour(new.reviewTime)) > 24  then signal sqlstate '22003' set message_text = 'Hrs greater than 24';
end if;
end;

Comment: just run this to enabled the trigger 
`mysql -u USERNAME -p
set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;`

Comment: @Dhaval Purohit thanks for the info but the problem is that Is it possible to enable the trigger without SUPER privilege?Because i have some restrictions for this which i can't do it...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then you may handle this using check constraints when you define your table:

```
CREATE TABLE mock_table (
    reviewTime time CHECK (HOUR(time) < 24)
    created_dt datetime
);
```

Technically a 24 hour day doesn't support `24:00:00`, because `23:59:59` automatically wraps around to `00:00:00` of the next day.

Comment: True but question specifically states  'in mysql 5.6.4'

Comment: Then the only option would be to use a trigger.  Moving forward, my answer would be useful to most other readers of this question.

Comment: Well, a trigger or an INSERT.

Comment: @tim biegeleisen But check constraints is not supporting in mysql 5.6.4 which i have mentioned....as you said using mysql 8+

Comment: @Strawberry Can you please be more specific about your answer?It would be more useful for me if you do so....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what @strawberry had in mind but you could test the time and force burst it

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(ts time);

insert into t values (if('20:00:00' > '23:59:59','840:00:00','20:00:00'));

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

insert into t values (if('37:00:00' > '23:59:59','840:00:00','820:00:00'));

ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect time value: '840:00:00' for column 'ts' at row 1

select * from t;

+----------+
| ts       |
+----------+
| 20:00:00 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @strawberry this query is correct but you are doing it manually,i mean you are setting the time manually not by code...

Comment: What is it that builds your insert statements?

Comment: i have tried by using TRIGGER but it's showing error like SQL Error [1419] [HY000]: You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable QUERY - create trigger check_capacity_on_insert
before insert on exp1.mock_table
for each row 
begin
if(hour(new.reviewTime)) > 24  then signal sqlstate '22003' set message_text = 'Hrs greater than 24';
end if;
end;

Comment: The trigger code is fine you should check that you have sufficient privileges to create one with your dba/security persons.

Comment: yeah i know i have sufficient privileges but i don't know how to disable this SUPER privilege setting in mysql 5.6.4 software.Can you please tell how to do this SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled ?

Comment: i can't have the access to GRANT the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled.....it's restricted to me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, t TIME NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table (t) SELECT '22:23:00' FROM (SELECT 1) n WHERE TIME_TO_SEC('22:23:00') BETWEEN 0 AND 86400;

INSERT INTO my_table (t) SELECT '212:23:00' FROM (SELECT 1) n WHERE TIME_TO_SEC('212:23:00') BETWEEN 0 AND 86400;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+----------+
| id | t        |
+----+----------+
|  1 | 22:23:00 |
+----+----------+
```

Comment: @DhavalPurohit Oh, you and I are going to have some fun together.